# Bash regex match

Tags: regex, bash

I want to match a line using a regular expression, but can quiet see why it won't work.

To explain my situation: say i have a script like this:

```
text="/location/whatever/
/some-other-stuff/
/this-is-what-i-need-1/
/this-is-what-i-need-2/
/this-is-what-i-need-3/
/some-other-random-stuff"

#now loop through it:
while read -r line
do
    if [[ "$line" =~ '\/[a-zA-Z\-]*[0-9]+\/' ]]
    then
        #do whatever you like
    fi
done <<< "$text"
```

I now want to only match lines in the form of "this-is-what-i-need-".
My first regex would've been this: `\/[a-zA-Z\-]*[0-9]+\/` but it doesn't seem to match any of these lines. I really would like to understand why that is so.

Comment: First thing I'd try is `/[a-zA-Z-]*[0-9]+/`

Comment: `[[ $line =~ /[a-zA-Z-]*[0-9]+/ ]]`

Comment: nice, that works, thank you. Can you explain why entering the regex without quotes did the thing?

Comment: Starting from ver 3.2, BASH doesn't support regex in quotes.

Comment: Thank you. Good to know when you come from pre 3.2

Answer (score 0):

I prefer one liners. You might want to check

```
echo "$text" | egrep '\/[a-zA-Z\-]*[0-9]+\/' | xargs -i echo "Do something with {}"
```

You can use any program instead of `echo`.

Comment: Since this is part of a larger scale program I prefer a more readable way to achieve this.